# Filter data in excel by date in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a excel sheet below

```
A         B                C
Name    Start Date  End Date
Ajay    6/2/2019    6/18/2019
Sham    6/3/2019    6/18/2019
Ramu    6/5/2019    6/18/2019
Ravi    6/7/2019    6/18/2019
```

Now I want to filter data by date in python

So I want to select the start date and end date

for example : 6/5/2019 to 6/18/2019

and the resuls should be :

```
A         B                C
Name    Start Date  End Date
Ramu    6/5/2019    6/18/2019
Ravi    6/7/2019    6/18/2019
```

How can i achieve this in python?

Thanks in advance

I have tried using this code but I cannot understand how to go further

`df[(df['date'] >= '02/01/2001') & (df['date'] <= '05/01/2001')]`

Comment: is that a multiindex or do you have columns as `A,B,C` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your date fields to `datetime` format with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), so you can apply the filters. You are now trying to apply calculations on `object(string)` type columns.

I use [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) here which stands for "greater than or equal", but you can just as well use `>=` and `<=`

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

df[df['Start Date'].ge('2019-06-05') & df['End Date'].ge('2019-06-18')]
```

---

```
   Name Start Date   End Date
2  Ramu 2019-06-05 2019-06-18
3  Ravi 2019-06-07 2019-06-18
```